# textbox value in JSP to Java scriptlet code in the same JSP

Tags: java

### I am using the below code in my JSP and I am getting the value in the textbox. But I need to get the same value printed in the textbox to the Java scriptlet which I have written in the sam JSP page. Here I will not post or submit the JSP page, as I need to make one column read-only based on the text box value in the edit page.

" "

### Can anyone please help me out in achieving the same?

```
                <%
                String batchIdValue = request.getParameter("batchid");
                System.out.println("^^^^^^^BATCH ID^^^^^^^"+batchIdValue);

                %>
```

---

input type="text" class="form-control" name="batchid" ng-model="ctrl.batch.id" value="ctrl.batch.id"

Comment: You mentioned "below code", but I believe you forgot to add that.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="batchid" ng-model="ctrl.batch.id" value="ctrl.batch.id" />

Comment: <%
     String batchIdValue = request.getParameter("batchid");
     System.out.println("^^^^^^^BATCH ID^^^^^^^"+batchIdValue);
     %>